# DropBox App without Confirmation

Tags: c#, dropbox, dropbox-api

I've written a really simple WPF app which uploads a backup in a specific interval to my DropBox. But I want to use this on my small WIN 2k3 server at home. This means I don't want to login via Internet Explorer etc. Just start the app with Windows. At the moment I need to confirm that my account can use this app. Is it possible to do this without confirmation? I followed [this](http://cgeers.com/2011/12/29/dropbox-rest-api-part-1-authentication/) guide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to process the authorization manually once, but you can then save and re-use the resulting access token (the one received from /access_token) for all future calls without further user intervention.